# Using text styling to create a list with sublists

Tags: php, regex, markdown, preg-replace-callback

I am trying to make markup to format an Ordered list, here is the markup style:

```
$strings = "1. dog
1. cat
1. fish
 1. horse
 1. monkey
1. pig
";
```

`horse` and `monkey` from that list should be part of a sublist, since they have one space before the number. Here is the code that I am using:

```
function blq($match){
    $str = preg_replace("/^1\. (.+?)$/m", "<li>$1</li>", $match[0]);
    $str = preg_replace_callback("/(?:^1\. .+(\n|$))+/m", 'blq', $str);
    return "<ol>$str</ol>";
}

$string = preg_replace_callback("/(?:^ ?1\. .+(\n|$))+/m", 'blq', $strings);

echo $string;
```

That code is creating this output:

```
<ol><li>dog
</li>
<li>cat
</li>
<li>fish
</li>
 1. horse
 1. monkey
<li>pig
</li>
</ol>
```

`horse` and `monkey` were not created as a sublist, but just ignored. I feel that I am getting close to the answer, but I am not sure what to do to get to that answer...

**Note** I would like to allow an unlimited number of sublists

Comment: Just curious about a few things. Wouldn't the `$1` in double-quotes attempt to interpolate? (Shouldn't they be in single-quotes?) Also, are you sure you intend to use the `/m` modifier? If so, the `(\n|$)` doesn't make sense to me, since `$` matches `\n`.

Comment: `$1` isn't a valid variable, so it is read as text. I am using `/m`, because I am doing a multiline search, so I think that would be correct. For `(\n|$)` I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$text = "1. dog
1. cat
1. fish
 1. horse
  1. duck
   1. goose
  1. swan
 1. monkey
  1. chimpanzee
  1. orangutan
  1. whale
1. pig
";

function callback($match) {
    $out = preg_replace_callback("/(^($match[2] +)1\. .+(\\n|$))(?1)*/m", 'callback', $match[0]);
    $out = preg_replace("/^$match[2]1\. (.+)$/m", "<li>$1</li>", $out);
    return "<ol>\n$out</ol>\n";
}

$html = preg_replace_callback("/(^( *)1\. .+(\\n|$))(?1)*/m", 'callback', $text);

echo $html;

?>
```

Here's [an ideone demo](http://ideone.com/rXO8N2).

---

That's a pretty neat idea you had, using `preg_replace_callback` recursively. Also, you're right about `$`-strings not interpolating within double quotes unless they're a set variable; I always forget that. And, you were right to use `/m` since you want `^` match the beginning of each line (not the beginning of the entire string) and you were also right to use `(\n|$)` despite that `$` matches the end of each line in `/m` mode—because otherwise, the quantifier `+` wouldn't work because `$` wouldn't actually *consume* the `\n`. I didn't see these facts when I first read your question.

Now, let's start with the first expression:

```
/(^( *)1\. .+(\\n|$))(?1)*/m
```

Actually, the recursive subexpression, `(?1)`, isn't necessary except as shorthand. Let's expand that:

```
/(^( *)1\. .+(\\n|$))(^( *)1\. .+(\\n|$))*/m
 |                  ||                  |
 +------------------++------------------+
```

So we have two identical halves. Why not just use `+` as you did? Because I want to capture the number of spaces indenting the *first* line, only. Those spaces get stored in `$match[2]`.

Within the callback, we bring those spaces back, plus one or more spaces:

```
/(^($match[2] +)1\. .+(\\n|$))(?1)*/m
```

That way, we only ever look at levels *beneath* the current level of indentation (*more* spaces), on each level of `preg_replace_callback` recursion. And as the recursions unwind, *only* the lines indented by exactly that level's number of spaces, `$match[2]`, are wrapped in `<li></li>`,

```
/^$match[2]1\. (.+)$/m
```

before returning the whole wrapped in `<ol></ol>`.

Comment: Very nice answer and even better explanation +1